# How to select multiple check box in edit grid section of magento

Tags: magento

http://magento.localhost.com/index.php/arithmetic/adminhtml_arithmetic/edit/id/5/key/c03c12d4c338a2e4cdbb93c3d9e511a93401d19b21a13ea77cffda20cac94577/

This is what my link looks like. I am getting all values by the ID, in the edit grid page

there is a section for multiple check boxes. How can I select all the check boxes according to the result array

```
$fieldset-> addField('st_user_interest', 'checkboxes', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Interest'),

        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'st_user_interest[]',
    'values'    => array(

        array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Education'),
            'value'     => 'education',
        'class'     => 'required-one',

        ),
        array(
           'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Business'),
            'value'     => 'business',
          'class'     => 'required-one',

        ),
        array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Marketing'),
            'value'     => 'marketing',
         'class'     => 'required-one',

        ),

        array(
            'value'     => 'investment',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Investment'),
         'class'     => 'required-one',
        )
        ),      

    ));
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi any one have any idea about it thanks

Comment: @Shatir hi do you have any idea about this issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi at the time of storing array field value we are storing as string after converting array to string,

So at the time of setValues() Magento looking for that same input field value as array to check the check boxes

Trick is that convert that stored string value into array and assign to that column field that will work

**Package_Arithmetic_Block_Adminhtml_Arithmetic_Edit_Tab_Form**

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{

 $id = $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('arithmetic_data')->getIn_user_id());
$model = Mage::getModel("arithmeti/newuser")->load($id);

/* here is the stuff witch converting the stored string to array and set in                          st_user_interest */
$interest = $model->getSt_user_interest();
$model->setSt_user_interest(explode(',',$interest));


    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('arithmetic_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('User information')));


  $fieldset-> addField('st_user_interest', 'checkboxes', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Interest'),

    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'st_user_interest[]',
'values'    => array(

    array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Education'),
        'value'     => 'education',


    ),
    array(
       'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Business'),
        'value'     => 'business',


    ),
    array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Marketing'),
        'value'     => 'marketing',


    ),

    array(
        'value'     => 'investment',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('arithmetic')->__('Investment'),

    )
    ),      

));

if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getArithmeticData() )
    {

        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getArithmeticData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setArithmeticData(null);
    } elseif ( $model->getData() ) {


    //Mage::registry('arithmetic_data')->getData(); /* removing this line and adding $model->getData() inslde the $form->setValues() */
        $form->setValues($model->getData());

    } 


    return parent::_prepareForm();

}
```